# Remove All Images from the_content in a Post?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Hello I want help to create a plugin to automatically remove all the images in the postings.

Possible solution add this code to your theme’s index.php file:

```
?php> 
echo preg_replace('/<img[^>]+./','',get_the_content()); 
?>
```

Convert this code into a plugin??

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `wp_kses` for this purporse. Add the filter for the `img` element using the `wp_kses_allowed_html` filter.

In your functions.php.

```
function theme_slug_kses_allowed_html($tags, $context) {
    switch($context) {
        case 'no-images': 
            $tags = wp_kses_allowed_html('post');
            unset( $tags['img'] );
            return $tags;
        default: 
            return $tags;
    }
}
add_filter( 'wp_kses_allowed_html', 'theme_slug_kses_allowed_html', 10, 2);
```

Then in index.php.

```
echo wp_kses( get_the_content(), 'no-images' );
```